# What is the syntax for using an ArrayList as a parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

Basically I want to make a separate method for a "method" that I have created in public static void main.

In this method, I manipulated an array-list and am not sure how to use an array list as a parameter in a function

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReverseArrayList{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  Note: I used a sample array with 6 elements. 
    //  I explain the code as if I am strictly using 6 elements
    //  However this may be done with any # of elements 
    ArrayList<String> reverseMe = new ArrayList<String>();
    reverseMe.add("I");   
    reverseMe.add("am");
    reverseMe.add("going");
    reverseMe.add("to");      
    reverseMe.add("be");
    reverseMe.add("reversed");

    //  This loop will run until we reach the midpoint of the array. At the midpoint, all the elements would be reversed
    for (int i = 0; i < reverseMe.size()/2; i++){

      //  Save the first three values for later use. 
      String initial = reverseMe.get(i);

      //  The 1st element will be assigned to the last element, upto the midpoint 
      reverseMe.set(i, reverseMe.get(reverseMe.size() - i - 1));

      //  The last element will be assigned to the 1st element, upto the midpoint
      reverseMe.set(reverseMe.size() - i - 1, initial);
    }
    //  Displays the contents of the arraylist
    for(String i: reverseMe){
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

I've researched for the syntax but couldn't find any good videos showing the syntax.

Comment: it's exactly the same as using any other datatype. what are you talking about?

Comment: The syntax for passing an arraylist as a method parameter is the same as passing any other type as a parameter. What did you try and what difficulty did you have?

Comment: Read about varargs. If you don't know how many params to expect, this is a good option

Comment: For example, If you want to use an array as a parameter, you would do:             int x[] as the parameter, what about arraylists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` implements `List` and hence you can use it as a parameter e.g.

```
public void testMethod(List<String> list){
//....rest of your code goes here
}
```

Always remember that objects are passed by reference and hence any modifications you do in list here will be reflected in the list in method from where this method is called.

Also, for your code java have a support for diamond operator i.e. you don't need to specify generic type on right side of `=`. And on left i.e. Reference variable should be Parent interface for the sake of maintainability e.g.

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1):

```
you just need something like below

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReverseArrayList{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  Note: I used a sample array with 6 elements. 
    //  I explain the code as if I am strictly using 6 elements
    //  However this may be done with any # of elements 
    ArrayList<String> reverseMe = new ArrayList<String>();
    reverseMe.add("I");   
    reverseMe.add("am");
    reverseMe.add("going");
    reverseMe.add("to");      
    reverseMe.add("be");
    reverseMe.add("reversed");
    reverseList(reverseMe);
  }
private static void reverseList(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
 //  This loop will run until we reach the midpoint of the array. At the midpoint, all the elements would be reversed
    for (int i = 0; i < reverseMe.size()/2; i++){

      //  Save the first three values for later use. 
      String initial = reverseMe.get(i);

      //  The 1st element will be assigned to the last element, upto the midpoint 
      reverseMe.set(i, reverseMe.get(reverseMe.size() - i - 1));

      //  The last element will be assigned to the 1st element, upto the midpoint
      reverseMe.set(reverseMe.size() - i - 1, initial);
    }
    //  Displays the contents of the arraylist
    for(String i: reverseMe){
      System.out.println(i);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I think  the keyword "void" is missing at method declaration.